# Passing back data to a Paused Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am having some trouble using intents to pass data between my Activities, specifically their appears to be a problem when I am passing data to a pervious activity when the current activity is paused.

From the first activity I start it like this:

```
//Create the activity we want to run and place it in an Intent
  Intent i = new Intent(activity, JVoiceActivity.class);

  //Create a bundle for passing some data.
  Bundle b = new Bundle();

  //Pass that this is a recording.
  b.putBoolean("Record", true);
  i.putExtras(b);

  //Start it.
  activity.startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```

The reason I am using activity instead of just startActivityForResult is because this is another class that I pass the activity to keep my project Object Orientated.

Then on the new Activity I close it like this:

```
 public void onPause()
 {   
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

   bundle.putString("Path", mPath);
   Intent i = new Intent();

   i.putExtras(bundle);

   setResult(RESULT_OK, i);

   super.onPause();
 }
```

Finally in the first Activity I have the function:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
 {
  if(data!= null)
  {
```

This function is being called but the Intent data is always null. I am assuming its the way I close the second activity as I did have this working before when I was testing it, at the time I was calling Finish() straight away from my second activity after setting mPath for testing purposes.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas to look at:

- The result will only be sent back to the calling Activity when the started Activity calls finish() (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29)
- onPause does not mean that your Activity is finishing, merely that it is pausing.  If the user is pressing the back-button for example it will Pause, but not finish the Activity. (see the Activity lifecycle documentation)
- In onActivityResult you should check the requestCode. I suspect you are getting RESULT_CANCELED because the called Activity doesn't finish() correctly before returning.

Comment: Thanks for your response; this has helped me resolve it now. The problem was with the Activity not finishing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The onPause method is designed to handle when anything closes your activity. So it should not hand the setResult() method. Place the setResult on some event and call finish() at the end.

Comment: Thanks for this answer also I have done as suggested and put the code from onPause into onBackPressed. Its resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should not call setResult() from onPause() because it is too late - the result is set in finish() method, which has been called before the onPause() method. Instead you can call setResult() form onBackPressed() or any other method that is executed before the call to finish()